# set background=dark in .vimrc does not change vims background

Tags: vim

I added `set background=dark` in my .vimrc but my vim is still with a light background.

Am I missing something? Do I have to compile something so that my changes are used?

Edit:
I am Using a Debian Stretch distribution and I had to reinstall vim, because I failed to use SpaceVim, but this Problem occured before as well.

I have also noticed this text in .viminfo:

```
:set background=dark
|2,0,1555...47,,"set background=dark"
```

I don't understand this snippet but I guess that this would not hinder vim to get the setting out of .vimrc(?)

Answer (score 1):

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27background%27

> When set to "dark" or "light", Vim will try to use colors that look good on a dark (or light) background.
>
> Setting this option does not change the background color, it tells Vim what the background color looks like.